# Programmatically setting explicit layout constraints constants for explicitly declared screen sizes (logical dimensions)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I am trying to get my head around how Auto-Layout and ***different explicit*** screen sizes works.

I just want these to explicitly different, and I will be setting the `.constant` for every supported device because trying to do it with layout editor, outdated Pod solutions, vary-for-traits, and auto-layout is a hap-hazard mess to me lol.  I don't mind doing by hand and it should make it incredibly easy to modify in future updates/modifications.

Here is a snippet of what I currently have and what I thought would be the answer but isn't.  When I run the simulator for both **iPhone 12 Pro Max** and **iPhone 12 mini** the trailing constraint on the object is identical and shows as `0`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var trailPadSet: NSLayoutConstraint!
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        displayBackGround.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.height == 780 { // <- this is iPhone Mini
            trailPadSet.constant = 120 // <- I set this to a wild constant to just see the difference noticeably.
        } else {
            trailPadSet.constant = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug! Does the line `trailPadSet.constant = 120` actually execute?

Comment: @matt It doesn't.  I get the error - ```screen parameters are unexpected: MGScreenClass1125x2436x3x495 SCREEN_TYPE(1125,2436,3,495)```  I've read that there may be a bug in xcode 12 and the iPhone 12 Mini.

Comment: Well done! Well, there's your answer. It doesn't change to 120 because you never changed it to 120. Perfect.

Comment: No bug; Why do you think that the iPhone 12 mini has a vertical resolution of 780? You have discovered the reason why your approach is probably not the best idea; you are going to have to hard code in lots of device details and you app will need to be tweaked every time Apple releases a new device.

Comment: @matt I mainly am trying to figure out *why* lol

Comment: @Paulw11 the iPhone 12 mini has a *physical* height of ‘2340’ but a *Logical* height of ‘780’.

Comment: @Paulw11 you can see that even with the actual height of the screen being 2340, the XCode error output says the 12mini simulator size is 2436. Hence the assumed “bug”. I’ve tried each of these and none of them work either unfortunately.

Comment: The screen `bounds` is just a silly way to try to identify a device type, especially because it can change. The whole idea of making layout depend on device type is silly too; it should depend on dimensions. Plus if you want to do some manual layout, viewDidLoad is the wrong place.

Comment: @matt I couldn’t find anything on how to detect the unique device with an IF statement. That’s the reason I went with the screen bounds.  Isn’t bounds how you define the constraint to dimensions?

Comment: No, the iPhone 12 mini reports a screen resolution of 2436 pixels or 812 points when you apply the scaling factor of 3 (https://useyourloaf.com/blog/iphone-12-screen-sizes/), but this approach will be a haphazard mess rather than designing a flexible layout with constraints.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ahhh now I see how it works. I still want to try and do this Pragmatically just because every other way I’ve seen involves going through multiple Menus and applying multiple factors from different tools. There’s no clear information on how to do it and it’s driving me crazy!  But I am hoping it’s just something I haven’t understood yet. Do you have any sources for information on actually doing what I what I want to do correctly?

Comment: I don't have any sources. IMO there is no way to do what you are trying to do correctly.  The whole approach is incorrect. With UIKit you should use constraints and autolayout. With SwiftUI you don't even need to do that

Comment: @Paulw11 Your correction of the size actually being 812 works and the scaling factor was what caused my error.  So thanks for clarifying that for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are checking == for checking device. You can do one thing check device name like below
UIdevice.current.name it will print device name and your code will work

Comment: What if I name my device "Sally"?  Including the model in the name is a default that Apple uses when you set up your device but it isn't mandatory.